# Jquery Autoscroll

Tags: jquery, html

I have a dropdown menu with multiple list items, which looks like this

```
<li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About Us <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="about_us.html" id="headbutton1">Heading1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="about_us.html" id="headbutton2">Heading2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="about_us.html" id="headbutton3">Heading3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

And in the about_us.html file I have these

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2 class="text-center" id="headbutton1">Heading 1</h2>
            <p>Test 1.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2 class="text-center" id="headbutton2">Heading 2</h2>
            <p>Test 2.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2 class="text-center" id="headbutton3">Heading 1</h2>
            <p>Test 3.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

so, when I click on the list items in the menu (say with id='headbutton2'), I need to load the about us page with the respective section (i.e. id='headbutton2') loaded.
I'm using the following jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var scrollPoint = $('#headbutton2').offset().top - 120;

        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: scrollPoint
    }, 'slow');


});
```

Comment: Do you want to go straight to that section in the about_us page, or do you want to go to the top of the about us page and then scroll to the relevant section?

Comment: go to the top of the about us page and then scroll to the relevant section

Comment: I've updated my answer to match this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to go to the relevant section on the page, you can add the trget to your links like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="about_us.html#headbutton1">Heading1</a></li>
  <li><a href="about_us.html#headbutton2">Heading2</a></li>
  <li><a href="about_us.html#headbutton3">Heading3</a></li>
</ul>
```

There is no need for the scrolling jQuery, as that link will send you directly to the section.

---

If you want to first land on the `about_us` page and then scroll to the relevant section, it's a little more involved, and you could use query strings for that.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="about_us.html?target=headbutton1">Heading1</a></li>
  <li><a href="about_us.html?target=headbutton2">Heading2</a></li>
  <li><a href="about_us.html?target=headbutton3">Heading3</a></li>
</ul>
```

and this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var q = document.URL.split('?')[1];
var target = q.split('=')[0] === 'target' ? '#' + q.split('=')[1] : '#';

    var scrollPoint = $(target).offset().top - 120;

        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: scrollPoint
    }, 'slow');

});
```

Note: This code will apply to every page, and you will need to change it if you ever want your query string to include other information, but if you're just using static pages it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll to specific div like this:

```
   var scrollPoint = $("#myDiv").offset().top;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: scrollPoint 
    }, 2000);
```

[Fiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/sagar_arora/8tLdq/4296/)